# Why i can't get access to public static variables on library class project from windows forms project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a library class project on the project i added a new User Control.
On the User Control top i added this variables:

```
public static string[] allfiles;
public static BackgroundWorker bgw;
```

Then in the bottom i have a click event:

```
private void menuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Upload")
            {
                allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(e.ClickedItem.Text, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

The click event is working fine i see that allfiles contianing the files and directories.
The problem is that in form1 constructor i can't get access to the variables allfiles and bgw
bgw i need it since i want that when the user make the click the backgroundworker1 in form1 will run.

In form1 in the windows forms project i dragged over the dll file of the library class project from the toolbox. And then i tried in the form1 constructor to do:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            explorerTree1.
```

But explorerTree1 dosen't contain allfiles or bgw
And i can't type just ExplorerTree in form1.

So how can i get access to variables also method/functions from class library project user control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your fields are declared `static`, which means they belong to your `ExplorerTree` type, not an instance of `ExplorerTree`.

If you want to access them, you'll need to do so on the type:

```
ExplorerTree.allfiles;
```

If what you need is to access them on an instance, don't declare them as `static`. I'd also recommend exposing them as properties, instead of public fields:

```
public string[] AllFiles { get; set; }
public BackgroundWorker Bgw { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You made them `static`, so they're on the type:

```
ExplorerTree.allfiles
```

If you don't want that, create instance properties:

```
public string[] AllFiles { get; set; }
```

Then you can access them through an instance:

```
explorerTree1.AllFiles;
```